# python: Right Click on list menu not showing item selected

Tags: python, wxpython, right-click

In my ongoing effort to learn more about python, I am trying to add a right click event to my mp3 manager program.  What currently works is that it shows the menu and all of the options.  What is not working is the functions selected from the menu are not executing as I think they should be.  Much of this code was taken from a 'how to' on another site.

Here are the right click menu options

```
menu_titles = ["Remove Selection from list",
               "Delete Selection from system",
               "Move Selection",
               "Copy Selection",
               "Print Selection"]

menu_title_by_id = {}
for title in menu_titles:
    menu_title_by_id[ wxNewId() ] = title
```

The code that is run when the right click event happens

```
def RightClickCb( self, event ):
    # record what was clicked
    self.list_item_clicked = right_click_context = event.GetText()

    ### 2. Launcher creates wxMenu. ###
    menu = wxMenu()
    for (id,title) in menu_title_by_id.items():
        ### 3. Launcher packs menu with Append. ###
        menu.Append( id, title )
        ### 4. Launcher registers menu handlers with EVT_MENU, on the menu. ###
        EVT_MENU( menu, id, self.MenuSelectionCb )

    ### 5. Launcher displays menu with call to PopupMenu, invoked on the source component, passing event's GetPoint. ###
    self.MainPanel.PopupMenu( menu, event.GetPoint() )
    menu.Destroy() # destroy to avoid mem leak

def MenuSelectionCb( self, event ):
    # do something
    operation = menu_title_by_id[ event.GetId() ]
    target    = self.list_item_clicked
    print 'Perform "%(operation)s" on "%(target)s."' % vars()
```

What I expect to get when I do a right-click and then select one of the options in the menu is the output

```
Perform "Print Selection" on "<data about the selection here>"
```

What I am getting is

```
Perform "Print Selection" on "."
```

How do I get the data from the item I have selected as part of my right click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use `event.GetString()` in place of `event.GetText()`

See [here](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CommandEvent-class.html)

Your code seems outdated tho, binding to events should be done like this:

```
menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.MenuSelectionCb, id=id)
```

moreover if you bind all ids to the same function you can just bind once for all ids:

```
menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.MenuSelectionCb)
```

Comment: Hmm - the item under selection is an object that is part of a list, not a single string.  How would you hand that?

Comment: @ccwhite1: [MenuItems](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MenuItem-class.html) does not allow coupling with client data (like [ListBox](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListBox-class.html#Insert) does) so I suggest you keep on using dictionaries using MenuItem id as key and your object as the value so you can retrieve it like self.my_data_dict[event.GetId()]

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution under [Python: Right click on objectlistview not showing item name selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36581286/python-right-click-on-objectlistview-not-showing-item-name-selected) where the use of objectlistview's `GetSelectedObject()` method is proposed instead.